# [C]--binary function

Tags: c, binary

I'm working in a small program using Language C.
I want to create a function which transform a decimal number to binary.
So i Have that:

```
#include< stdio.h>

int *binaire(int nb,int base)
{  
    int d,i=0,j;
    int *tab= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    while(nb>0){
        tab[i]=(nb%base);//inverser  les bits    
        nb=nb/base;
        i++;
    }

    return tab;
}
```

please Help

Thxs

Comment: There is certainly no need on gods earth to use malloc here.

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: You are tasked with converting a decimal number to a binary number. I don't see any decimal number in your program.

Comment: People are being stupidly critical of easily-understood question.  Go use the restroom.  The use of malloc is needed, to return the pointer.  Knee-jerk criticism, ah, yes, I'm on SO.

Comment: The return value of malloc has type `void*` and shouldn't be cast. Casting it is redundant and, more importantly, may hide the error of not including the proper header. Also you should check for NULL.

Comment: @Heath And returning an int by value would be too difficult?

Comment: @Heath, if you are referring to me, my response wasn't intended to be critical. I seriously believe that the OP is misunderstanding the requirements of his assignment, and tried to highlight that misunderstanding. I did this for the OP's edification; either my comment will prompt them to a greater understanding, or they will ask more questions, which will lead them to understanding.

Comment: @unapersson - You still haven't thought about the question.  OP's mistake is that he needs more than one int.  See taskinoor's answer.  Smart remarks without thinking about the question: knee-jerk stupid criticism.

Comment: @Rob, I was in part referring to you.  If you read the code, it's obvious that nb refers to the number to be converted, and base is the base of conversion (i.e., "2").  You can discern that from the math.  Given this information, does the OP need to give you an example number, such as, say "17", for you to figure out what they are doing?  Considering they appear to be a native Francophone, perhaps you could be a little more helpful in figuring out what's already been stated in the question rather than nitpicking the word "decimal number."

Comment: @Heath I don't know that he needs more than one int because the question does not make that clear - to put it mildly.

Comment: @Neil - Perhaps you would like OP to go away because his English isn't up to your standards and you can't figure out what C code is supposed to do based on a trivial snippet of code.  For goodness sake, considering that there's an ```i++``` in there and a ```tab[i]```, this should be easy.  Yet, only taskinoor has the brains to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethign along those lines:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct value_
{
  int* digits;
  int nb_digits;
} value;

value* base_convert(int nb,int base) ;

value* make_value(int nb, int base)
{
  value* v = malloc(sizeof(value));
  if(v)
  {
    v->nb_digits = 1+round(log(nb)/log(base));
    v->digits    = malloc(sizeof(int)*v->nb_digits); 
    if(v->digits) base_convert(v, nb, base);
  }

  return v;
}

void destroy_value(value* v)
{
  if(v->digits) free(v->digits);
  free(v);
}

void base_convert(value* v, int nb,int base) 
{
  int i; 

  for(i=0;i<v->nb_digits;++i)
  { 
     v->digits[v->nb_digits-i-1]=(nb%base);//inverser les bits
     nb=nb/base;
  }

  return v;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  value* v = make_value(137,2);
  for(i=0;i<v->nb_digits;++i)  printf("%d",v->digits[i]);

  destroy_value(v);

  return 0;
}
```

This needs :

- a get_digit function to mask the rough access to value::digits

Number of digits is computed using log to be generic. The abse 2 version can be computed in a faster way using bitshifts.

Comment: of course, it smells homework. I don't know what you're supposed to use but keep in mind that structure are always easier to manipulate.

Comment: The return value of malloc has type `void*` and shouldn't be cast. Casting it is redundant and, more importantly, may hide the error of not including the proper header. Also you should check for NULL.

Comment: yup, surely. I wrote this quickyl . Lemme edit.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` returns the size in bytes, not in bits. May be you are looking for this:

```
int *tab= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 8);
```

EDIT: As pointed in the comments, there are other problems here. Please check them too.

EDIT2: The previous code contains a bug in calculation. I am assuming that you are trying to store the bits in an `int` array. So the array will contain `sizeof(int) * 8` integers, all either zero or one. So the code will be:

```
int arraySize = sizeof(int) * 8;
int *tab = (int *) malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
```

In fact you don't need to use full `int` to store a single bit. One byte character is enough to store a bit.

Comment: That `8` should probably be `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @Carl Norum, that will be better, no doubt.

Comment: The return value of malloc has type `void*` and shouldn't be cast. Casting it is redundant and, more importantly, may hide the error of not including the proper header. Also you should check for NULL.